# Write XLSX file - Oracle forms

Tags: forms, oracle, xlsx

i am trying to create xlsx file based on block data in oracle forms.

Is it possible to generate xlsx using webutil(Text_io) or by using java beans?

any sample please share me.

thanks
V

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion and experience it is best using UTL_File to generate text file then open it with Excel. You can use Text_IO also. If I find the example I will post it.